# Play Framework 2.2 log output to console in tests

Tags: logging, playframework-2.0

How do I configure the logger in Play Framework 2.2 in order that I see log output in the console during play integration tests?

The configuration for Play Framework 2.1 does not work anymore.

BR Rene

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have not done this yet, but you have to configure a logback configuration file. See the play documentation for additional information: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/SettingsLogger

Once you defined a specific logback configuration file, this needs to be placed in the test package, see this issue for details:https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1669#issuecomment-24452132

See message from **@benmccann**: *you can configure the logger in test mode by placing a logback-test.xml in test/resources (took me hours to figure out!).*

Answer (score 6):

**Update** To understand more about how logback is configured you should pass `-Dlogback.debug=true` property to the jvm/play. This might save you hours of debbugging.

Add a file in `test/logback-test.xml` (needs to be on classpath so it might depend on how the play application is configured to find tests resources) with a content like

```
<configuration>

    <conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel"
        converterClass="play.api.Logger$ColoredLevel" />

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${application.home:-.}/logs/application.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date - [%level] - from %logger in %thread
                %n%message%n%xException%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%coloredLevel %logger{15} - %message%n%xException{5}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="play" level="INFO" />
    <logger name="application" level="INFO" />

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: the file has to be placed in the conf/ folder and play will use it.

Comment: As a side note, ${application.home} is not defined for play unit tests so  it would be ok for play integration tests were you create a fake application, but for unit tests that variable is not defined hence the log file would be created on <play_project_folder>/application.home_IS_UNDEFINED/logs/application.log (tested on play 2.3.6)

Comment: For a more general working log setup, you can use the default value syntax ":-" for logback variable substitution: ${application.home:-.}  Docs: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#defaultValuesForVariables