# Setting logging level for FakeApplication

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2, specs2

I am trying to configure the logging level of FakeApplication in my Specs2 test cases. However, the override isn't being picked up at all. It seems like it is always loading from logger.xml.

Any thoughts how I can override the logging level for FakeApplication properly?

**Clarification:** I am not too worry about Specs2 test log, but I am more concern about setting service log level.

**Clarification 2:** I am setting up `it` (integration test) instead of unit test, have a separate folder `it/` for it under the main project.

```
abstract class SmtpServer(
) extends WithServer(
  app = FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = Map(
    "logger.root" -> "OFF"
  )),
  port = 99
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To configure your logs for testing you must create a `logback.xml` file in the `test/resources` directory of your project.

@see https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1669#issuecomment-24452132

@see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/SettingsLogger

@see [Play Framework 2.2 log output to console in tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999294/play-framework-2-2-log-output-to-console-in-tests)

--

Comment: I tried to clone logger.xml to logback-test.xml and put it into it/resources/ or conf/ both doesn't work. Also tried to specify -Dlogger.file and -Dlogger.resource, still doesn't work. It is always picking up logger.xml, I can confirm it because if I remove CONSOLE output from logger.xml, the log really gone from STDOUT...:(